# External Content Type method in ECMAScript

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

Currently I am working on SharePoint Online (Office 365) project. I used Sandbox solution and WCF service for my project according to business requirement.

I have created an External Content Type (BCS) using WCF service as well as defined External List from it. There are some operations of WCF service which are not configured with any external list.

How can I call these operations in my visual web part using ECMAScript? Is there any other solution for the same?

Please help me I am very new to SharePoint development. Thank for your help.